# How to list all categories and tags in a page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, categories

Suppose we have few categories, tags and custom post type and taxonomies. How can we list all categories, tags in a page? Something like;

> Page
>
> Category Thumbnail and Category Name 1(link to category page)
>   Description
>
> Category Thumbnail and Category Name 2(link to category page)
>   Description
>
> Category Thumbnail and Category Name 3(link to category page)
>   Description
>
> Divider
>
> Tag Thumbnail and Tag Name 1(link to Tag page) Description
>
> Tag Thumbnail and Tag Name 2(link to Tag page) Description
>
> Tag Thumbnail and Tag Name 3(link to Tag page) Description

Same with custom post type and taxonomies.

*And if the description and thumbnail are not possible then only a name with link will be adequate.*

Most of this is achievable by these plugins.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-column-taxonomy-list/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-column-tag-map/

Right now I'm looking in plugin code to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TERM METADATA**

It's possible to get thumbnails for terms using the new Term Metadata in 4.4. You just also need to define those ahead of time yourself.

- [`add_term_meta( int $term_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, bool $unique = false )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)
- [`get_term_meta( int $term_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)
- [`update_term_meta( int $term_id, string $meta_key, mixed $meta_value, mixed $prev_value = '' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)

---

**CATEGORIES**

[get_categories ( )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) Returns an array of category objects matching the query parameters.

```
echo "Categories:<br/>";

$args = array( 
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC', 
    'public'                   => true,
); 

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
     echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
}
```

---

```
echo "<hr>"; // divider
```

---

**TAGS**

[get_tags ( )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) Retrieves an array of objects for each term in post_tag taxonomy.

```
echo "Tags:<br/>";

$args = array( 
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'public'                   => true,
); 

$tags = get_tags( $args );

foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
     echo '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a><br/>';
}
```

**TAXONOMIES**

[get_taxonomies ( )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies) Get a list of registered taxonomy objects.

```
echo "Taxonomies:<br/>";

$args = array(  
    '_builtin'                 => false, 
    'public'                   => true,
); 

$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args, 'objects' ); 

foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
    echo '<p>' . $taxonomy->labels->name . '</p>';
}
```

**POST TYPES**

[get_post_types ( )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) Returns the [registered post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) as found in $wp_post_types. [get_posts ( )](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) creates an array of posts based on a set of parameters so use it with your post_type_list.

```
echo "Post Types:<br/>";

$args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
);
$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$post_types = get_post_types($args, $output, $operator);

// get all the posts for all post_types

$posts = get_posts(array(
                           'post_type'   => $post_types,
                           'numberposts' => - 1,
                           'orderby'     => 'post_type',
                           'order'       => 'ASC',
                           'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
                           'public'      => true,
                       ));

foreach($posts as $post) {

    $link = get_permalink($post);
    $title = $post->post_title;

    if($post_type !== $post->post_type) {
        $post_type = $post->post_type;
        echo '</br/><p>' . $post_type . '</p></br/>';
    }

    // show link to post

    echo "<p><a href=\"$link\">$title</a></p>";
}
```

**TRANSIENT CACHING**

If you want to cache the results of all these queries then consider the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). This will store the result into the database for a limited time (which you ~request~). It's not a certain timeframe because plugins like [WP Optimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize/) can clear the cache anytime.

```
// check if the value exists using the key -- if it fails then we'll generate the content

if(false === ($trans_value = get_transient($trans_key = 'my_transient_key'))) {

    print_r('NO CACHE FOR ' . $trans_key); // (debug output)

    // start the output buffer to capture our generated content

    ob_start();

    // run your expensive operations -- data sent to the screen will be captured

    print_r('This is an expensive operation!');

    // using ob_get_clean we'll store the results and set the value variable.

    // double check the amount of time you want to keep the data cached
    // set to 0 for auto loading on every page hit.

    set_transient($trans_key, $trans_value = ob_get_clean(), 1 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS);
}
else {
    print_r('THIS IS A CACHED RESULT FOR ' . $trans_key); // (debug output)
}

// value is ready and cached
print_r("<pre>$trans_value</pre>");
```

To clear the value just delete using the key.

```
delete_transient ( $trans_key );
```

Comment: Note: Passing term id's to `get_*_link()` functions are expensive. `get_term_link()` (*which is used by all `get_*_link()` functions*) queries the db to get the term object via `get_term_by()`. You should always, where possible (*like in your examples*), pass term objects to `get_*_link()` functions. This way, these functions do not need to make a db call to get the term object

Comment: Also, your function to get posts according to post type is quite expensive, you can do all of that in one query

Comment: The `type` parameter in `get_categories` does not relate to the post type, but to the type of taxonomy, either `category` or `link_category`. This parameter is depreciated since the introduction of custom taxonomies in version 3.0, and IIRC, it used to accept only `link` as value which meant it should get terms of the taxonomy `link_category`

Comment: I didn't see your notes on https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/WordPress_Performance.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think there is no problem in finding better solution, if anyone have better solution they can edit answer if possible, give new answer or in comment. Community should get benefit, right/wrong doesn't matter.